# How to convert URI to real path in marshmallow?

Tags: java, android, uri

I have an image URI and I want to convert this URI to a real path. I've looked at lot of of answers but none worked for me. I'm using marshmallow 6.0.1. The image URI is `content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A52530`.

Code:

```
   sendImageFromFolder.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                     Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setType("image/*");
                    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
                    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Picture"), 1);

                }
            });

     protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

     if(requestCode==1) {
          Uri uri = data.getData();//how to convert this uri to real path .
    }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Uri` is not a `File`. A `Uri` does not have to represent a file on the filesystem that you can access. The `Uri` might point to content that is:

- stored on removable storage, which you cannot access
- stored on internal storage of another app, which you cannot access
- stored in an encrypted form, where a `ContentProvider` needs to decrypt it
- stored in a BLOB column of a SQLite database, where a `ContentProvider` needs to load it and serve it
- stored in "the cloud", where a `ContentProvider` needs to download it
- generated on the fly, the way this Web page is
- and so on

You can use `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` to get an `InputStream` on the content represented by the `Uri`. You can create a `FileOutputStream` on some file that you control. And, you can use Java I/O to copy from the `InputStream` to the `OutputStream`, making your own copy of the content in a file that you control.